# How can I transform parts of an Integer list to a String list

Tags: functions

There is a sorted list of Integers.

```
ilist = PadRight[Sort[ RandomSample[Range[1, 99999], 3], Less], 5]
```

It should become string area codes like:

```
{0123, 023345, 043563, 0, 0};
```

with trailing zeros.
Can I do this with one function?

```
slist=ReplaceAll[ilist,n_Integer :>"0"<>ToString[n]]
```

Note: last elements are zeros already and should not double.

Comment: Doe `ReplaceAll[ilist, n_Integer :> "0" <> ToString[n] /; n =!= 0]` work for you?

Comment: `slist=ReplaceAll[ilist,n_Integer/;n!=0:>"0"<>ToString[n]]` aha, same to Sjoerd

Comment: these will leave 0 as an integer no?.  could do ReplaceAll[ilist,n_Integer :> If[n==0,"0","0" <> ToString[n] ]]

Comment: If you export it as .csv you have to import it back as file.csv,"Text".   .   .Then your zeros are coming in to.   .   I like your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do this is to PadRight with the zero string...

```
ilist = PadRight["0" <> ToString@ # & /@ 
          Sort[RandomSample[Range[1, 99999], 3], Less], 5, "0"]
```

(* {027082, 039217, 085143, 0, 0} *)

```
Head /@ ilist
```

(* {String, String, String, String, String} *)